# Error when deploying a Cloud Function with gcloud: Could not validate source files: [[Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm trying to follow [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-functions-go-http/#0) getting started guide to use Cloud Functions with `gcloud` and Go. The guide is meant to be working in the cloud but I'm trying to do it from my local console.

This is the code of my Cloud Function:

```
func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, Uj.")
}
```

When I try to deploy it by running the following `gcloud` command:

```
gcloud functions deploy HelloWorld --runtime hello-world-uj-1994 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated
```

I get this error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) Error building source archive from
>   path [.]. Could not validate source files: [[Errno 2] No such file or
>   directory: './.erlangInstaller/default']. Please ensure that path [.]
>   contains function code or specify another directory with --source

Any idea on how I can solve this path problem? And do you know what does Erlang have to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that I'm seeing is that you are using `--runtime hello-world-uj-1994`.

In the deploy of the tutorial you can see they are using `--runtime go111`

These are the following [accepted runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--runtime)

Comment: Indeed I mixed my project name with my runtime option... I'm sorry. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Glad we got it sorted quickly! Cheers.